# How to create a processor in nifi using curl Rest API?

Tags: curl, apache-nifi, dbm, process-group

I want to create a processor inside a processor group in nifi. I want to create it using the curl command in ubuntu cli. I don't know exactly how to create a processor? I know it can be started using JSON commands. I couldn't find any examples to do it using it.

Comment: Use browser with devtools open (f12) to create whatever you need in nifi. Track network requests and reproduce them in your code.

Comment: And there is a nifi api documentation https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html

Comment: I tried with the browser console but couldn't recreate it. So I am searching for an example which I could do it.

Comment: https://snyk.io/advisor/python/nipyapi/example for python